# Change a TextView value in a custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

Suppose we have this example:

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html

with source code available here:

http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/Phonebook/src/com/abeanie/

How can we modify a mobile phone number once clicked on the list item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the method `onItemClick()` get the `PhoneBook` element corresponding to the position(the position parameter) of the row clicked, update the value and then notify the adapter that the data has changed with a call to the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long index) {
                // make the adapter a field in your class (or final)
                PhoneBook element = (PhoneBook) adapter.getItem(position);
                //modify the PhoneBook element
                element.setPhone("555-555-555");
                // notify the adapter that something has changed
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                showToast(listOfPhonebook.get(position).getName());
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried lots of example and this works for me!!Great work